# The Basics needed for creating a map in D3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I want to create a simple map in D3js.  I am using Sublime Text as a text editor. I have created an html document, and I have downloaded the D3js library v 3, and topojson.js.  I have gone to geojason.io and have saved data to a json file.  I am using a template for a D3 map of Boston that I found on Github and am running it from my laptop, but I get the following message in console:
d3.v3.min.js:1 Failed to load file:///Users/CJlandry/Desktop/D3js/World%20Map%20with%20TopoJson/map-2.topojson: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https. and then
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined at Object. (index.html:34)at Object.t (d3.v3.min.js:1) at XMLHttpRequest.i (d3.v3.min.js:1)at Object.Cn.u.send (d3.v3.min.js:1)at Object.u.(anonymous function) [as get] (https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:1:10904)atCn(d3.v3.min.js:1)at Object.ao.json (d3.v3.min.js:5)at index.html:32

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need a local server. If you're using Windows, I suggest WAMP. If you're using a Mac, I suggest MAMP.

Comment: OK.  Thank you !